# ASP.NET MVC - Getting username of the user using my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and creating a little application in my spare time at work.

This application has windows authentication and connects to one of our remote test databases, and the application does some simple select/update/insert queries with one of the tables on this database.

For one part of my application, when a user clicks 'process', I save that user's username in my model by doing:

```
job.User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

And then write that to the database.

Everything run's fine when I run it locally through visual studio, it recognises my domain name/username and saves that to the database.

Once publishing to IIS, I ask one of my team members to connect to my computername/site and when they try to click that same 'Process', they get

"Login failed for user 'OURDOMAINNAME/MYCOMPUTERNAME$'. "

My application is using DefaultAppPool with Identity set as 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'.

My whole team has permissions to access this database and if only my application picked up their correct domain group/username then it would OK but the application is trying to connect as MY computer and not my actual windows logon.

Can anybody please advise?

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with [tag:c]? And are you *really* using MySQL?

Comment: @DavidG accident, and using SQL Management Studio

Comment: So not MySQL either. Please take care when tagging questions.

Comment: What authentication are you using for your site?

Comment: @DavidG sorry, new to this website.

Comment: @Wheels73 Windows

Comment: Is anonymous authentication disabled as well?   The account under which your site runs in the app pool is the account used to access resources.. e.g. database. Suggest you set up a production domain account and add that login to sql server and give it access to the require db's etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ApplicationPoolIdentity, did you allow that user in your MSSQL database?

User: IIS APPPool\DefaultAppPool

Comment: I need to do this even if the SQL server is on a remote server?

Comment: Yes or you could change your connection string to use SQL authentication instead of Windows authentication.